# when using python logging.Formatter() can I use a pep8 style or does it have to be on one line

Tags: python, logging, pep8

I'm learning how to use the python logging module and wanted to know if it's possible to split the code below so the variables are easily readable and identified:

```
formatter_f = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s,%(levelname)s,%(module)s,%(funcName)s,%(message)s',datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

which results in:

```
03/25/2022 09:51:28,WARNING,main,<module>,first
03/25/2022 09:51:28,ERROR,sub2,div,error happened: division by zero
03/25/2022 09:51:28,WARNING,main,<module>,done
```

I tried to do a more pep8 style with this:

```
        formatter_f = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s,\
            %(levelname)s,\
            %(module)s,\
            %(funcName)s,\
            %(message)s',
            datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

but it produced this:

```
03/25/2022 10:01:32,            WARNING,            main,            <module>,            first
03/25/2022 10:01:32,            ERROR,            sub2,            div,            error happened: division by zero
03/25/2022 10:01:32,            WARNING,            main,            <module>,            done
```

I also tried to set each part as it own variable so i could set a sinlge master sting and keep each var on it's own line, like

```
        asctime = "asctime"
        levelname="levelname"
        module="module"
        funcName="funcName"
        message="message"
        date_format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"

        file_format_string =f"%({asctime})s,%({levelname})s,%({module})s,%({funcName})s,%({message})s', datefmt={date_format}"

        formatter_f = logging.Formatter(file_format_string)
```

When the program ran nothing was logged to the file and this error showed up in console:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Is there a way to organize the `logging.Formatter()` with each var on its own line or am I stuck with this being a single huge line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sequence of adjacent string literals, which will automatically be concatenated by the compiler.

```
formatter_f = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s,'
                                '%(levelname)s,'
                                '%(module)s,'
                                '%(funcName)s,'
                                '%(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```